# Change message content with INet on Omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am trying to simulate a WSN on Omnet and since I want it to be wireless, I chose the Inet Framework.

Now I need to personalize the Content of the Messages sent but I can't find a way to do so.

can anybody help me with that? I can't find anything in the unser Manual etc.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is "the Message" and from which module you want to send it.
If you are creating/testing application protocol then you might want to create new .msg file which describes the structure of your message.

INET's documentation has a section on working with packets https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/developers-guide/ch-packets.html#representing-packets

The `.msg` file can look something like this:

```
cplusplus {{
const B YOUR_APP_HEADER_LENGTH = B(6);
}}

class YourAppHeader extends FieldsChunk
{

    chunkLength = YOUR_APP_HEADER_LENGTH;

    int someField;
    bool someBit;

};
```

then in your C++ code

```
Packet *packet = new Packet();
const auto& payload = makeShared<YourAppHeader>();
payload->setChunkLength(B(<someValue>));
payload->setSomeFiled(<intHere>);

packet->insertAtBack(payload);

//and then send it
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already heard from the message files. Can you tell me how to include the message files into my network? I can't find any explanation on this. And I thought when I use the INet Framework, there is no c++ code, so I'm wondering about the last part of your answer.

Comment: If you want to use existing INET models, you don't need to touch the C++ code. But you want to change the actual message and that (AFAIK) cannot be done with NED.